# 'inputFile' component issue in ADF JDeveloper 11g

Tags: java, upload, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am using an inputFile component in jsff page where the user can browse the file system, select the file in order to store it in the database.

I created a `ValueChangeListener` method for this component which deal with this file and store it in db.

The problem is, once the user select the file it appears for a second in the page and it disappears and the `ValueChangeListener` is not called.

Note: the `AutoSubmit` property is set to `true` for this component. I am using JDeveloper 11g with ADF.

Comment: Please give us your exact jdev version!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If autsubmit set to true, then your file is being submit as soon as user chooses it.
You may want to turn it off and submit it when user clicks the **submit** button.

If your **value** property ain't preserved after submit (for example if you point to bean in backingBean scope), you will have no value as soon as submit completes. You can save it in viewscope variable for example.

[Here is nice sample](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E18745_01/devguide/fileUpload.html) of how file uploads should be done.

Don't forget to set `<af:form usesUpload="true">`.

And one more [link with Demo App included](http://andrejusb.blogspot.ru/2013/04/multiple-file-upload-unlimited-file.html).

Comment: Thank you Nagh, I was missing the usesUpload property. My problem solved when I add <af:form usesUpload="true"> to the form. Thanks again.